# Python scrapy and Regex check string from file and scrape

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

While creating a scraper, I encountered a situation where I have a bunch of keywords and there are too many to hard code. So I wanted to implement a regular expression that reads from a "dictionary" file, it contains the keywords, and when the crawler / scraper matches one of the keywords on a certain website it scrapes the whole paragraph containing the keywords.

A single paragraph scraping model of the code is looking like this :

```
for Keyword in response.xpath('//*'):
        yield {
            'dictA':  Keyword.xpath('//p/text()[contains(..,"Specific Keyword/s")]').extract(),             
        }
```

This is what gets me the whole paragraph that this "Specific Keyword/s" contains. But I have, let's say around 100 words, I don't want to do:

```
dictA1
.
.
.
dictA100
```

It is inefficient. How could I go behind this. As always hints and pointing helps and is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process list of keywords and check each one against some XPath expression you can use this:
for Keyword in response.xpath('//*'):

```
for specific_keyword in keyword_list:
    yield {
        'dict':  Keyword.xpath( '//p/text()[contains(.,"{0}")]'.format(specific_keyword) ).extract(),             
    }
```

**UPDATE** 
After some clarifications from you:

```
for word in keyword_list:
    for para_text in response.xpath('//p/text()[contains(..,"{0}")]'.format(word)).extract():        
        yield {
            'dict':  para_text,             
        }
```

Comment: So, help me understand. The specific_keyword would be a word from the file (.csv if it helps)? Because from what I get it would translate as `for word_in_file in file: yield text that contains word_in_file`? If that is the case, then I need a way to make this with 100 keywords, not just a single one. But I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @schneejäger first you need to read your keywords (from a CSV file, database or something else) into `keywords_list`

Comment: By that you mean to `keyword_list: open("file.csv", "rt")`, yes?

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: It throws an error `'str' object has no attribute 'xpath' ` because there isn't a response.xpath to guide it. Maybe I'm applying it wrong to my example.

Comment: I think you're trying to apply `.xpath()` to your keyword... Please show your current code

Comment: ` def parse(self, response):
        in_file = tuple(open("dictionaryA.csv", "r"))
        
        for link in response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/article/div/div[2]'):
            yield {
                'dictA1':  link.xpath('//p/text()[contains(..,"Pasta")]').extract(),             
            }` 
This is the one working.
`for word in in_file:
            yield {
                'dictA': word.xpath('//p/text()[contains(.,"{0}")]'.format(word)).extract(),
            }`
This would be with what you have provided me.

Comment: Please show your HTML and explain what did you mean by `Keyword in response.xpath('//*'):`

Comment: `link in response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/article/div/div[2]'):` this would be the `Keyword in response.xpath('//*'):` you refer to, I changed some names in the original question.

Comment: We've advanced, got a new problem `ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters`.

Comment: I can't code for you. Obviously your last error doesn't related to your original question

Comment: Obviously, just wanted to let you know of the advancement. Thank you!